# Vue binding ref in renderless component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this problem where binding `ref` in renderless component won't work. I've tried adding `class` within the `instance object` and the `class` binding work but the `ref` didn't. I also tried logging `this.$refs` and it just returns an empty object.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <renderless>
      <div slot-scope="{ instance, logger }">
        <div v-bind="instance"></div>

        <button @click="logger('One')">One</button>
        <button @click="logger('Two')">Two</button>
      </div>
    </renderless>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Renderless from "./components/Renderless";

export default {
  components: {
    Renderless
  },
};
</script>
```

**components/Renderless.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  render(h) {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      instance: {
        ref: 'container'
      },
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init()
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      console.log(this.$refs)
    },
    logger(value) {
      console.log(value)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How can I bind the `ref` so that the child component know what element to target or any other better solutions/suggestions?

BTW code is also available on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzw7m9q5n9).

Comment: One option is to use querySelector to pick out what you want within the child component. So within `init()` you might have something like `const buttons = this.$el.querySelectorAll('button');` and in your case for the html you provided, it will return an array of the two buttons you have in the slot.

Comment: Yeah, I already know that solution. Sorry for not specifying in my question. Maybe there is another vuejs like solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to pick out what you want within the child component. `this.$el` should provide the based element of the child class once the component has mounted.

```
init () {
  const buttons = this.$el.querySelectorAll('button');
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    // access each button
  });

  // fetches an item by element id
  const itemById = this.$el.querySelector('#elementid');

  // fetches by classes
  const itemsByClass = this.$el.querySelector('.className');
}
```